# Counting votes from SQL Server and displaying it using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database

I am making an Android app for mobile voting, and to support that I have made some .aspx pages.

I am stuck at a point where I have to make a page in which vote count along with the contender name and the party name should be shown.

I have a table `RegisterContender` in a SQL Server database which consists of the columns `ContenderName` and `PartyName`. I also have a table `castVote` which consists of the column `ContenderName` for which the voter has voted.

Now what I want to do is to count the number of `ContenderName`(s) for which the voters have voted and display it in the format `Name PartyName TotalVotes`

```
String _view = String.Format("select count(*) as numVotes,ContenderName from castVote where ContenderName IS NOT NULL group by ContenderName order by numVotes desc");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(_view, con);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{

    String _ans = String.Format(dr["numvotes"].ToString()+" "+dr["ContenderName"].ToString());

    Response.Write(_ans);
}



create table RegisterContender
 (ContenderId int identity(1,1) Primary Key Not Null,
  Name varchar(100),
  PartyName varchar(100),
  History varchar(1000),
 Future_Proposals varchar(500),
 Region varchar(150)
)

 create table castVote
 (VoterLogin varchar(100),ContenderName varchar(100))
```

the relationship between these two is that the ContenderName from castVote is same as the Name in the RegisterContender. PartyName is also present in the RegisterContender.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please let us know what have attempted so far and give us as much information as possible.

Comment: alright... i have counted the votes and i m able to display the names and votes... but i am not able to figure out how to display the PartyName which is present in another table i.e RegsiterContender

Comment: i have updated my details @logixologist you can see them.

Comment: You'll need to join on the second table.  Please post the schema of the two tables and indicate their relationship.

Comment: @Tim i have updated the details.. you can see them